# Cannot authenticate with Kerberos with PuTTY, but can with WinSCP

Tags: windows, ssh, putty, winscp, kerberos

I've been using PuTTY with Kerberos authentication to connect to a server for work, but accidentally overwrote my settings with a blank template (not sure why the Save and Load buttons are right next to each other...). Now, even when I believe I have the settings set up the same way they were before, I can't connect using PuTTY; I get the error message

> Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent:  )

I've seen plenty online about when that message returns with the server sending pubkey, but my message has the server sending nothing, which I can't find online. I've tried getting a new Kerberos key, letting PuTTY look for the key manually, and specifying the `gssapi32.dll` file myself, all to no avail.

What is strange to me is that WinSCP will connect to the server just fine, and there's nothing special in the connection settings there. However, when I have WinSCP open a PuTTY session I get the same error message when I try to connect. I've already checked to make sure WinSCP isn't just opening an already saved session, and it didn't solve the problem.

I am on Windows 10 using PuTTY version 0.70 and WinSCP version 5.13.3

EDIT: As requested, here are the logs from the PuTTY and WinSCP sessions:

PuTTY:

```
    =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~= PuTTY log 2019.06.07 10:11:18 =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=
Event Log: Writing new session log (SSH packets mode) to file: putty.log
Event Log: Connecting to 131.225.64.57 port 22
Event Log: We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.70
Event Log: Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
Event Log: We believe remote version has SSH-2 channel request bug
Event Log: Using SSH protocol version 2
Event Log: Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
Event Log: Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-256
Event Log: Server also has ssh-dss host key, but we don't know it
Event Log: Host key fingerprint is:
Event Log: ssh-rsa 2048 3d:3f:3f:b4:37:90:97:a7:28:a6:bf:3d:e8:40:0b:d4
Event Log: Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
Event Log: Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm
Event Log: Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
Event Log: Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm                                   .
Event Log: Using SSPI from SECUR32.DLL
Event Log: Attempting GSSAPI authentication
Event Log: GSSAPI authentication initialisation failed
Event Log: No credentials are available in the security package.
Event Log: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: )
```

WinSCP:

```
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.839 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.840 WinSCP Version 5.13.3 (Build 8565) (OS 10.0.17763 - Windows 10 Home)
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.840 Configuration: HKCU\Software\Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2\
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.840 Log level: Normal
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.840 Local account: MATT-OMEN\mattd
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.840 Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.840 Process ID: 19196
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.840 Command-line: "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" 
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.840 Time zone: Current: GMT+2, Standard: GMT+1 (Romance Standard Time), DST: GMT+2 (Romance Daylight Time), DST Start: 3/31/2019, DST End: 10/27/2019
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.841 Login time: Friday, June 7, 2019 10:04:51 AM
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.841 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.841 Session name: DarkSide (Site)
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.841 Host name: ds50srv01.fnal.gov (Port: 22)
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.841 User name: mdowning (Password: No, Key file: No, Passphrase: No)
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.841 Tunnel: No
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.841 Transfer Protocol: SFTP (SCP)
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.841 Ping type: Off, Ping interval: 30 sec; Timeout: 15 sec
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.841 Disable Nagle: No
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.841 Proxy: None
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.841 Send buffer: 262144
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.841 SSH protocol version: 2; Compression: No
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.841 Bypass authentication: No
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.841 Try agent: Yes; Agent forwarding: No; TIS/CryptoCard: No; KI: Yes; GSSAPI: Yes
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.841 GSSAPI: Forwarding: No; Libs: gssapi32,sspi,custom; Custom: 
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.841 Ciphers: aes,chacha20,blowfish,3des,WARN,arcfour,des; Ssh2DES: No
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.841 KEX: ecdh,dh-gex-sha1,dh-group14-sha1,rsa,WARN,dh-group1-sha1
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.841 SSH Bugs: Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.841 Simple channel: Yes
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.841 Return code variable: Autodetect; Lookup user groups: Auto
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.841 Shell: default
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.841 EOL: LF, UTF: Auto
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.841 Clear aliases: Yes, Unset nat.vars: Yes, Resolve symlinks: Yes; Follow directory symlinks: No
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.841 LS: ls -la, Ign LS warn: Yes, Scp1 Comp: No
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.841 SFTP Bugs: Auto,Auto
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.841 SFTP Server: default
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.842 Local directory: C:\Users\mattd\OneDrive\Documents\PocarLab\walter, Remote directory: /ds50/app/user/mdowning/simul, Update: Yes, Cache: Yes
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.842 Cache directory changes: Yes, Permanent: Yes
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.842 Recycle bin: Delete to: No, Overwritten to: No, Bin path: 
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.842 DST mode: Unix
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.842 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.875 Looking up host "ds50srv01.fnal.gov" for SSH connection
. 2019-06-07 10:04:51.894 Connecting to 131.225.64.57 port 22
. 2019-06-07 10:04:52.371 We claim version: SSH-2.0-WinSCP_release_5.13.3
. 2019-06-07 10:04:53.263 Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
. 2019-06-07 10:04:53.263 We believe remote version has SSH-2 channel request bug
. 2019-06-07 10:04:53.263 Using SSH protocol version 2
. 2019-06-07 10:04:53.263 Have a known host key of type rsa2
. 2019-06-07 10:04:53.633 Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
. 2019-06-07 10:04:53.896 Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-256
. 2019-06-07 10:04:54.655 Server also has ssh-dss host key, but we don't know it
. 2019-06-07 10:04:54.655 Host key fingerprint is:
. 2019-06-07 10:04:54.655 ssh-rsa 2048 3d:3f:3f:b4:37:90:97:a7:28:a6:bf:3d:e8:40:0b:d4 txbqNaAYtPldQ6hr/OlzTnoKdxEd4e/EB6q7PcGR7n0=
. 2019-06-07 10:04:54.689 Host key matches cached key
. 2019-06-07 10:04:54.690 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
. 2019-06-07 10:04:54.690 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm
. 2019-06-07 10:04:54.690 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
. 2019-06-07 10:04:54.690 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm
! 2019-06-07 10:04:55.998 Using username "mdowning".
. 2019-06-07 10:04:56.607 Server offered these authentication methods: gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
. 2019-06-07 10:04:56.612 Using GSSAPI from GSSAPI32.DLL
. 2019-06-07 10:04:56.612 Attempting GSSAPI authentication
. 2019-06-07 10:04:56.934 GSSAPI authentication initialised
. 2019-06-07 10:04:57.340 GSSAPI authentication initialised
. 2019-06-07 10:04:57.340 GSSAPI authentication loop finished OK
. 2019-06-07 10:04:57.716 Access granted
. 2019-06-07 10:04:57.716 Opening session as main channel
. 2019-06-07 10:04:58.891 Opened main channel
. 2019-06-07 10:05:01.318 Started a shell/command
. 2019-06-07 10:05:01.353 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2019-06-07 10:05:01.353 Using SFTP protocol.
. 2019-06-07 10:05:01.353 Doing startup conversation with host.
> 2019-06-07 10:05:01.367 Type: SSH_FXP_INIT, Size: 5, Number: -1
< 2019-06-07 10:05:01.675 Type: SSH_FXP_VERSION, Size: 95, Number: -1
. 2019-06-07 10:05:01.675 SFTP version 3 negotiated.
. 2019-06-07 10:05:01.675 Unknown server extension posix-rename@openssh.com="1"
. 2019-06-07 10:05:01.675 Supports statvfs@openssh.com extension version "2"
. 2019-06-07 10:05:01.675 Unknown server extension fstatvfs@openssh.com="2"
. 2019-06-07 10:05:01.675 We believe the server has signed timestamps bug
. 2019-06-07 10:05:01.675 We will use UTF-8 strings until server sends an invalid UTF-8 string as with SFTP version 3 and older UTF-8 strings are not mandatory
. 2019-06-07 10:05:01.675 Limiting packet size to OpenSSH sftp-server limit of 262148 bytes
. 2019-06-07 10:05:01.675 Changing directory to "/ds50/app/user/mdowning/simul".
. 2019-06-07 10:05:01.675 Getting real path for '/ds50/app/user/mdowning/simul'
> 2019-06-07 10:05:01.675 Type: SSH_FXP_REALPATH, Size: 38, Number: 16
< 2019-06-07 10:05:01.869 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 79, Number: 16
. 2019-06-07 10:05:01.869 Real path is '/ds50/app/user/mdowning/simul'
. 2019-06-07 10:05:01.869 Trying to open directory "/ds50/app/user/mdowning/simul".
> 2019-06-07 10:05:01.869 Type: SSH_FXP_LSTAT, Size: 38, Number: 263
< 2019-06-07 10:05:02.375 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 37, Number: 263
. 2019-06-07 10:05:02.375 Getting current directory name.
. 2019-06-07 10:05:02.422 Listing directory "/ds50/app/user/mdowning/simul".
> 2019-06-07 10:05:02.422 Type: SSH_FXP_OPENDIR, Size: 38, Number: 523
< 2019-06-07 10:05:02.674 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 13, Number: 523
> 2019-06-07 10:05:02.674 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 13, Number: 780
< 2019-06-07 10:05:03.706 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 1451, Number: 780
> 2019-06-07 10:05:03.706 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 13, Number: 1036
< 2019-06-07 10:05:04.619 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 1036
< 2019-06-07 10:05:04.619 Status code: 1
> 2019-06-07 10:05:04.619 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 13, Number: 1284
. 2019-06-07 10:05:04.619 ..;d;0;2018-08-13T16:23:41.000Z;3;"mdowning" [52643];"darkside" [9985];rwxr-s--x;0
. 2019-06-07 10:05:04.620 max_s1_frac_cut_fixed_acceptance_full_stats.root;-;3947179;2017-04-21T17:28:37.000Z;3;"mdowning" [52643];"darkside" [9985];rw-r--r--;0
. 2019-06-07 10:05:04.620 setup_root;-;357;2017-04-21T17:28:37.000Z;3;"mdowning" [52643];"darkside" [9985];rw-r--r--;0
. 2019-06-07 10:05:04.620 setup_root~;-;0;2017-04-21T17:28:37.000Z;3;"mdowning" [52643];"darkside" [9985];rw-r--r--;0
. 2019-06-07 10:05:04.620 my_copy;d;0;2017-04-21T17:28:57.000Z;3;"mdowning" [52643];"darkside" [9985];rwxr-sr-x;0
. 2019-06-07 10:05:04.620 TBA.jpg;-;10746;2017-05-09T16:06:24.000Z;3;"mdowning" [52643];"darkside" [9985];rw-r--r--;0
. 2019-06-07 10:05:04.620 .generic.C.swo;-;20480;2017-05-05T01:10:51.000Z;3;"mdowning" [52643];"darkside" [9985];rw-r--r--;2
. 2019-06-07 10:05:04.620 Tdrift.jpg;-;11275;2017-05-09T16:12:33.000Z;3;"mdowning" [52643];"darkside" [9985];rw-r--r--;0
. 2019-06-07 10:05:04.620 .generic.C.swp;-;16384;2017-04-25T20:27:08.000Z;3;"mdowning" [52643];"darkside" [9985];rw-r--r--;2
. 2019-06-07 10:05:04.620 generic.root;-;4036;2017-05-16T14:47:57.000Z;3;"mdowning" [52643];"darkside" [9985];rw-r--r--;0
. 2019-06-07 10:05:04.620 generic.C;-;16398;2017-05-16T14:31:41.000Z;3;"mdowning" [52643];"darkside" [9985];rw-r--r--;0
. 2019-06-07 10:05:04.673 Startup conversation with host finished.
. 2019-06-07 10:05:10.430 Closing connection.
. 2019-06-07 10:05:10.430 Sending special code: 12
. 2019-06-07 10:05:10.431 Sent EOF message
```

Comment: Do you have GSSAPI _enabled_ in PuTTY auth settings? Do you use "GSSAPI key exchange"? Are you using MIT Kerberos, Heimdal, or the built-in Windows (Active Directory) Kerberos client?

Comment: I do, I have both "Attempt GSSAPI authentication" and "Allow GSSAPI credential delegation" enabled. Where would I find "GSSAPI key exchange"? I am using MIT Kerberos.

Comment: Show us WinSCP session log file and PuTTY event log.

Comment: I added those as edits to the main post.

Comment: Is that 32-bit or 64-bit PuTTY? Which version of MIT Kerberos do you have installed, and did it come with a 64-bit version of GSSAPI32.DLL?

Answer (score 1):

WinSCP uses `GSSAPI32.DLL`:

> . 2019-06-07 10:04:56.612 Using GSSAPI from GSSAPI32.DLL

While PuTTY uses `SECUR32.DLL`:

> Event Log: Using SSPI from SECUR32.DLL

---

You are using 64-bit PuTTY.

64-bit PuTTY before version 0.71 incorrectly tries to load 32-bit version of MIT Kerberos DLL. This obviously fails and PuTTY falls back to Microsoft SSPI (which is probably not set up on your system, so it fails too). This was [fixed in PuTTY 0.71](https://git.tartarus.org/?p=simon/putty.git;a=commit;h=55efbc56a0f482d237b2315efac42c2f3301d986).

So either upgrade to PuTTY 0.71. Or if you you are stuck with an older PuTTY version, you have to manually specify a path to 64-bit DLL in *"User-supplied GSSAPI library path"* box at *"Connection > SSH > Auth > GSSAPI"*

Comment: In Connection > SSH > Auth > GSSAPI, the first item in the list "Preference order for GSSAPI libraries" is MIT Kerberos GSSAPI32.DLL, so I am not sure why PuTTy is trying to use SECUR32.DLL. Also, in the bin directory for MIT Kerberos there is both gssapi32.dll and gssapi64.dll - does this mean I have both bitnesses? If not, how can I determine the bitness of my Kerberos?

Comment: What PuTTY do you have? 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: In the "About" window, it says the build platform is 64-bit Windows... does that mean I have 64-bit PuTTY?

Comment: There's a bug in PuTTY 0.70. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be solved after looking at the bitness of all of the software. I was running 64-bit PuTTY, but it was trying to look for the 32-bit Kerberos file. I directed it to the 64-bit Kerberos file, and I was able to connect to the server. Thank you to Martin and grawity!